# how can i use multi-select in bootbox

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, multi-select

I want to use bootstrap-multiselect  in modal.
Im using a modal tools bootbox(http://bootboxjs.com/documentation.html) to do this, but cant get it to work; because multiselect need init.
But when I use it in box, I cant find anyway to write `js` in box.

How can I do this?

**Js**

```
$("#hello2").on("click", function () {
        var id = 0;
        bootbox.dialog({
            message:  '<div>ghostcard:<input type="text" name="first_name" id="ghostCard"/> </div><br> <div>water card:<input type="text" name="first_name" id="waterCard"/></div>   ' +
                    '       <select class="multiselect dropup" multiple="multiple" id="multiObject"> <option value="cheese">Cheese</option></select>',
            title:       "<small>hello</small>",
            buttons:{
                success:{
                    label:"confirm",
                    className:"btn-success",
                    callback:function () {
                        id = 2;
                        alert("id is " + id+$("#ghostCard").val()+$("#waterCard").val());
                    }
                },
                danger:{
                    label:"cancel",
                    className:"btn-danger",
                    callback:function () {
                        alert("id is " + id);
                        id = 3;

                    }
                }
            }


        });


    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Hoping this will help, but I found you can call the message as a function to enable you to do init, etc. within and simply return the message result. So instead of the message as a string invoke is as a function;
message: function () {
// Create/Init Dropdowns
return any text you want as the message.
}

I found this very helpful for tying in functionality such as the json-editor within the actual dialog body.

All the best,
Cheers

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xdyl/va54w/6/ can you give me a example? i dont really understand how to use function in message.multi-select muse use init. this usfiddle give an resolution of how to init it .but it have one second delay.